# document.getElementByClassname, it is not work

Tags: javascript, html

> My html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="./js/index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="aaa"></div>
    <div class="aaa"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

> My javascript

```
let b = document.getElementsByClassName("aaa");

console.log(b);
console.log(b.length);
console.log(b[0]);
```

I could see HTMLCollection in Chrome, it's show

**length : 2**

**0: div.aaa**

**1: div.aaa**

The problem is I want to change style, but I can't. So I try somethings below.

And I can not understand the output.

```
console.log(b);         //HTMLCollection
console.log(b.length);  // 0
console.log(b[0]);      // undefined
```

Why?

Comment: Are you dynamically adding these elements to your DOM?

Comment: If I run the last to console.log statements they seem to work fine https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/bruvtxzq/

Comment: This should work. It seems like there's some context that you're leaving out. Try to create a minimal reproducible example

Comment: Please provide us a more complete code sample.  Ideally we need a [mre]

Comment: @ShamPooSham Protip:  you can save keystrokes and provide a link by using `[mre]` in a comment.  It auto-expands to what you see in my comment.  See [magic links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments/94000#94000)

Comment: I don't know what is dynamically adding mean.  I try this in VsCode and use sever LIVE extension.

Comment: @Amy Thanks, didn't know that

Comment: @TyT Dynamically means those elements aren't part of the original HTML code, and were added using JavaScript.

Comment: getElementsByClassName is a selector and it returns a collection take a look at this example: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_document_getelementsbyclassname_loop

Comment: @TyT Can you please create a JSFiddle with an example where this happens? I can't reproduce

Comment: I put elements inner of <body>  tag

Comment: @ShamPooSham First time to use JSFiddle, I hope it's OK. https://jsfiddle.net/ur31t920/

Comment: @TyT Thanks, but `console.log(b.length)` outputs 2 for me here. So you must be doing something else in your project

Comment: In chrome console. I got this.

DevTools failed to parse SourceMap: chrome-extension://gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom/include.preload.js.map

Is it the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<script src="./js/index.js"></script>`

must be put place after the tag

```
<div class="aaa"></div>
<div class="aaa"></div>
<script src="./js/index.js"></script>
```

if put before tag, `js` can not read tag

Answer (score 1):

You can change styles as following:

```js
function bgChanger() {
  let x = document.getElementsByClassName("example");
  
  for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }
}

function resetBg() {
  let x = document.getElementsByClassName("example");
  
  for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.backgroundColor = null;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="example">
A div with class="example"
</div>
<div class="example">
 A div with class="example"
</div>
<br/>
<button onclick="bgChanger()">Change bg colors</button>
<button onclick="resetBg()">Reset bg colors</button>
```